# Best practices for writing to memsql using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, scalability, singlestore

My usecase is as follows: We are reading and transforming data from HDFS using Spark. The transformed data should be saved in memsql.

Are there any best practices for writing into memsql with Spark? I.e., what is the best way to ensure write performance and scalability when doing massive (parallel) writes using a Dataframe?

What is the preferred solution: Using the memsql/Spark connector (https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector) or a DataFrame's "write" method (in combination with the MySQL JDBC driver).

To make a longs story short: How can Spark scale writes to memsql?

Answer (score 1):

The MemSQL/Spark connector has some optimizations specific to memsql which can improve performance compared to writing via the mysql driver.

You should also take a look at MemSQL Streamliner (http://docs.memsql.com/latest/spark/), which allows you to easily set up pipelines to load data into memsql with Spark and does a lot of the work to manage scalability for you.